# DL a file with Ruby Open-URI with brackets in the filename

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to download a file using Ruby and Open-URI but I'm running into a problem with filenames containing brackets ( '[' and ']' ).

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/square-brackets-in-urls) page, brackets in URLs in this position is invalid because they're supposed to be encoded before that point.  An example URL that I'm trying to retrieve would be:

```
"http://torrent.zoink.it/National.Geographic.Desert.Seas.PDTV.XviD.MP3.[MVGroup.org].torrent"
```

How do I retrieve such a file with Ruby Open-URI? Googling has not revealed helpful results besides that link. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_encoding) (urlencode) the brackets. Since you just want to replace the brackets, and not encode any other charaters, I'd just `.sub` them in.

```rb
url = url.sub("[", "%5B").sub("]", "%5D")
```

Comment: Apparently I have to wait 8 more minutes before I accept your answer, but +1 and Thank You!