# URL detection and BB-Style tags (regex, look-ahead issue)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback, regex-lookarounds

so I'm building a small CMS and I'd like to avoid allowing HTML in the content editor. For that reason I want to detect raw URLs in text aswell as supporting BB-like tags, for better customization.

```
www.example.com
[link http://www.example.com]Click me[/link]
```

Unfortunately I'm fairly new to regular expressions and I just can't seem to get this working. I'm running two regular expressions over the string: The first detects raw URLs, the second BB-like URLs. The latter seems to work perfectly fine, the first one interferes though, and converts URLs wrapped in tags too.

I started off with a piece of code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php) and made some additions.

This is the code for non-tag URLs:

```
/* don't match URLs preceeded by '[link ' */
(?<!\[link\s)
(
    /* match all combinations of protocol and www. */
    (\bhttps?://www\.|\bhttps?://|(?<!//)\bwww\.)

    /* match URL (no changes made here) */
    ([^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))

    /* but don't match if followed by [/link] - THIS DOESN'T WORK */
    (?!\[/link\])
)
```

The negative look-behind before the `www.` is there because `/` isn't a word character, and without it something like

```
 [link http://www.example.com]example[/link]
```

would still match after `http://`.

The regex above produces the following matches (tested with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, matches are in **bold**. I had to add spaces after `http://`because I'm not allowed to post more URLs):

> **www.example.com**
>   **http:// www.example.com**
>   **http:// example.com**
>   [link http://www.example.com]no problem 1[/link]
>   [link www.example.com]no problem 2[/link]
>   [link http://www.example.com]**http://www.example.com[/link**]

I've tried moving the negative look-ahead around and played with the parentheses (pretty aimlessly), without success.

For completeness, here's the tag-matching regex (which seems to work):

```
(?:\[link\s)(\bhttps?://|\bwww\.|\bhttps?://www\.)([^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))\](.*)(?:\[/link\])
```

I'm sure someone can spot the error immediately.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The `(?!\[/link\])` lookahead will fail because PCRE will successively make the previous match shorter to succeed. You might need to make the URL matching super greedy. Try `(?> ...)` to make it atomic.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I tried making the various groups atomic, without success (I'm not sure I completely understood atomic groups though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your regex, insterted it into regexr with the examples you have given and tried to make it work.

**Step by step:**

1) The original regex: http://regexr.com?33snj. The problem why this regex also matches the [/link]  is in the URL matching bit:

```
[^\s()<>]+
```

This will also match the open bracket character '[', therefore matching will not stop when it encounters the [/link] bit. It could be argued that the [ character is a valid URI character, but that is only under rare conditions (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/square-brackets-in-urls) stackoverflow post for more info).

2) I decided to continue with your regex, but added the open bracket char to the negated character list:

```
[^\s()<>[]+
```

This will get you into another problem. See http://regexr.com?33snp. Because of backtracking the engine now finds a way around the negative lookahead at the end.

3) Once you make the URL matching group atomic (by adding ?> to the start of the capture group) the engine stops backtracking and we have arrived at the desired outcome.

```
(?<!\[link\s)((\bhttps?://www\.|\bhttps?://|(?<!//)\bwww\.)(?>[^\s()<>[]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))(?!\[/link\]))
```

See it in action http://regexr.com?33sns.

Comment: I actually experimented with adding the opening bracket to the negated characters as well, but stopped persuing this solution  because of concerns with some URLs no longer being detected (besides it not working because I didn't make the capture group atomic) - however, with of the link you provided I'm now perfectly satisfied with this solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I understand the concern. This url match is simple, but does the job. I wouldn't just allow brackets though. Instead I would go for recognition of IPv6 adresses in the url.

Comment: Also I am not sure why you need this (?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)) behind the url matching bit. It might be worth your while to look into better url-matching patterns. Just be careful not to include the brackets in the match :)