# http_build_query function's excessive urlencoding

Tags: php, url, query-string, urlencode

Why when building a query string with `http_build_query` function, it urlencodes square brackets `[]` outside values and how do get rid of it?

```
$query = array("var" => array("foo" => "value", "bar" => "encodedBracket["));
$queryString = http_build_query($query, "", "&");
var_dump($queryString);
var_dump("urldecoded: " . urldecode($queryString));
```

outputs:

```
var%5Bfoo%5D=value&var%5Bbar%5D=encodedBracket%5B
urldecoded: var[foo]=value&var[bar]=encodedBracket[
```

The function correctly urlencoded a `[` in `encodedBracket[` in the first line of the output but what was the reason to encode square brackets in `var[foo]=` and `var[bar]=`? As you can see, urldecoding the string also decoded reserved characters in values, `encodedBracket%5B` should have stayed as was for the query string to be correct and not become `encodedBracket[`.

According to [section 2.2 Reserved Characters of Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#sec-2.2)

> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by
>   characters in the "reserved" set. These characters are called
>   "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
>   the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
>   implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm. If
>   data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved character's
>   purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be
>   percent-encoded before the URI is formed.
>
> reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
> gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," /
>   ";" / "="

So shouldn't `http_build_query` really produce more readable output with characters like `[]` urlencoded only where it's required? How do I make it produce such output?

Comment: Why do you think it makes sense for only some brackets to be encoded and not others?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Because why encode something that doesn't need to be encoded, why produce more bytes than needed?

Comment: By that logic, `[` should never be encoded. But it is, because it /may/ have meaning depending on the target scheme. `http_build_query` does not have the necessary information to decide that.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Wrong. `http_build_query` has all the information for that, it knows full well what in the provided input is an array and what is a value and which values contain special characters like `[]` and which don't.

Comment: But it doesn't know what you're going to *do* with the resulting query. Are you passing it as POST formdata? Or a GET query string? Or is it even going in an HTTP request at all? Maybe it's for use with a custom scheme specific to the user's machine, that might use `[]` for some special purpose since they are reserved by the standards.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Both GET and POST use the very same `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format for the query. And did you notice `http` in the name of `http_build_query` function?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick function I wrote to produce nicer query strings. It not only doesn't encode square brackets but will also omit the array key if it matches the index.
Note it doesn't support objects or the additional options of `http_build_query`. The `$prefix` argument is used for recursion and should be omitted for the initial call.

```
function http_clean_query(array $query_data, string $prefix=null): string {
    $parts = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($query_data as $key=>$value) {
        if ($prefix === null) {
            $key = rawurlencode($key);
        } else if ($key === $i) {
            $key = $prefix.'[]';
            $i++;
        } else {
            $key = $prefix.'['.rawurlencode($key).']';
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (!empty($value)) $parts[] = http_clean_query($value, $key);
        } else {
            $parts[] = $key.'='.rawurlencode($value);
        }
    }
    return implode('&', $parts);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I think it's still relevant today.

**TL;DR**: http_build_query() is working correctly

Longer explanation: Yes, `http_build_query` encodes `[]` and it looks awful... but it's the correct behavior: `[]` are *reserved character* as per [rfc3986#section-2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.3). And... no, **they are NOT reserved for passing arrays**!

What `[]` are reserved for is defined in [rfc3986#section-3.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2):

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version
> 6    [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal
> within square brackets ("[" and "]").  **This is the only place where**
> **square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax**.  In
> anticipation of future, as-yet-undefined IP literal address formats,
> an implementation may use an optional version flag to indicate such a
> format explicitly rather than rely on heuristic determination.
>
> ```
>   IP-literal = "[" ( IPv6address / IPvFuture  ) "]"
>
>   IPvFuture  = "v" 1*HEXDIG "." 1*( unreserved / sub-delims / ":" )
> ```

So basically it is reserved for something like `https://[2607:f8b0:4004:808::200e]`

There is another questione about this same topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016737/1204976

Answer (score 0):

I found the following "fix" [here](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/074ve4gcjm/http-arrays#20070427x6wbsf3vgx7kcvh993bff4gt4m):

> [...] the workable 'fix' I have been using was to postprocess http_build_query() output
>   with the following - a 'solution' which makes my skin crawl just a little:
>
> ```
> function http_build_query_unborker($s) {
>     return preg_replace_callback('#%5[bd](?=[^&]*=)#i', function($match) {
>         return urldecode($match[0]); 
>     }, $s);
> }
> ```

So now it would become:

```
$query = array("var" => array("foo" => "value", "bar" => "encodedBracket["));
$queryString = http_build_query_unborker(http_build_query($query, "", "&"));
var_dump($queryString);
var_dump("urldecoded: " . urldecode($queryString)); // var[foo]=value&var[bar]=encodedBracket%5B
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Hehe, I just copied the code from that link. You're right and I got rid of the ev[ia]l `e` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You've got many questions here. Speaking in RFC terms of should, and reading your own questions in these same terms. I take your questions from bottom to top:

> How do I make it produce such output?

By using a different encoder, **Net_URL2** ([pear](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/) / [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/pear/net_url2)) for example:

```
$vars = array("var" => array("foo" => "value", "bar" => "encodedBracket["));

$url = new Net_URL2('');
$url->setQueryVariables($vars);
$query = $url->getQuery();

var_dump($query); // string(41) "var[foo]=value&var[bar]=encodedBracket%5B"
```

> So shouldn't `http_build_query really` produce more readable output with characters like [] urlencoded only where it's required?

No, it should not. Even it is not required to encode the square brackets inside the query part, it is recommended. That what is recommended should be done.

Next to that, the `http_build_query()` function is not about creating *"more readable output"*. It is only about creating the query of an HTTP URI. For such a query part, square brackets should be percent-encoded. These are reserved characters not specifically allowed for query.

> What was the reason to encode square brackets in `var[foo]=` and `var[bar]=`?

The reason to encode square brackets there is the same reason to encode square brackets in `encodedBracket[`. The differentiation you do between these parts in your question is purely syntactic on your own, within an URI these parts are treated equal. There are no sub-parts of a query part in an URI. So making a distinction between the bracket `var[` or the bracket `encodedBracket[` is purely unrelated to URI encoding of the query part.

As you say that the percent-encoding of `encodedBracket[` to `encodedBracket%5B` is correct and as it belongs into the same part of the URI (the query part), logic dictates that you must accept that encoding the bracket in `var[` to `var%5B` is equally correct in terms of URI encoding. Same URI part, same encoding. The only ending delimiter the query part has is "`#`".

Additionally your reasoning shows a misunderstanding in this part:

> As you can see, urldecoding the string also decoded reserved characters in values, `encodedBracket%5B` should have stayed as was for the query string to be correct and not become `encodedBracket[`.

If you urldecode, all percent-encoded sequences will be decoded - regardless whether the percent-encoding was representing a reserved character or not. In terms of correct, it's the opposite of what you stated: `%5B` has to be decoded to `[` regardless if it was at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of the string.

> Why when building a query string with `http_build_query` function, it urlencodes square brackets [] outside values and how do get rid of it?

It's easier to answer the second part, see at the beginning of the answer, it's already answered.

About the why this perhaps might not be immediately visible especially as you might have found out that PHP itself accepts percent-encoded and verbatim square brackets in the query (even intermixed) without any problems.

How come the differences and why is that so? Is it really as simple as you outline it in your question? Is this a cosmetic difference only?

First of all, not encoding square brackets in the query query part of an URI violates [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) in the sense that the query part *should not* contain the brackets from gen-delims characters unencoded. Non-percent-encoded square brackets can not be part of query according to the ABNF:

> ```
>  query         = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
> ```

> ```
>  pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
> ```

> ```
>  unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> ```

> ```
>  pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDI
> ```

> ```
>  sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

Getting rid of these therefore is not suggested (at least for encoding purposes following the standard) as it will change the URI:

> URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its
> corresponding percent-encoded octet are not equivalent.

This is already a good hint that for the URI you ask for, it has a different meaning than the URI PHP creates via the built-in function.

And further on:

> URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that
> correspond to characters in the reserved set unless these characters
> are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that
> component.

This is not the case for all characters in gen-delims *but* per the ABNF:

```
"/" / "?" / ":" / "@"
```

So it therefore looks like that `http_build_query()` went the route to percent-encode square brackets as those are reserved characters and *not* specifically allowed by the URI scheme for that part (the query). Basically nothing wrong with it, it follows the recommendation of RFC3986. And it is not suggesting a *different meaning* for those parts of the query.

However you clearly say, that technically these brackets aren't delimiters in the query. And yes, that is true:

> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

So comparing to what has been identified earlier as reserved characters *not* specifically allowed:

```
"#" / "[" / "]"
```

(already a pretty small list) it should be clear that "`#`" must stay reserved otherwise the URI gets broken (a true, separating delimiter at the end of query), but the square brackets must not be specifically allowed when representing an unequal URI without data-loss and preserving all URI delimiters:

> If a reserved character is found in a URI component and
> no delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be
> interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that
> character's encoding in US-ASCII.

So if you can still follow me, one might want actually do what you're asking for: Creating an URI in which the square brackets meaning as a delimiter (e.g. representing a fraction of an array definition) but not having this as data. Albeit the data of the character is preserved per RFC 3986.

It therefore is technically possible to create an URI with the square brackets not percent encoded within the query. Technically even inside values, like it would be a syntactical difference outside of values, this is only another syntactic difference for inside of values.

This is also the reason why browsers *preserve* the state of square brackets within the query when you enter these into your browser. Percent-encoded or not - the browser passes that part of the URI as-is to the server so that the underlying processes on the server can benefit from syntactic differences that might have been expressed by that.

So choose the URL encoding correctly for the underlying platform. Only because it's possible, it must not mean it works in a stable manner. The way `http_build_query()` does is the most stable (safe) way following RFC 3986. However it's a should in the RFC, so if you understand this to the point, you can have valid reasons to not percent-encode the square brackets.

One reason you name in your question is readability. This is especially important when you write down URLs for example on a sheet of paper. I'm not so sure if a square bracket is such a good distinguishable character and if not percent encoding does even help with readability. But I have not tried it. PHP would accept both ways. But then you won't need to do that programmatically. So perhaps readability wasn't really the case in your scenario.

Comment: Readability is one reason: important in debugging. The other thing is: there is a limit on the length of query string. Server side it's usually about 8k. Browsers may make it lower, but that's not our case. Anyway, if you pass a large array as parameters it becomes unnecessary bloated.

Comment: @Kalmar: Which is why you can find a different URL encoder at first which has the wanted encoding (or at least can be more fine-grained configured). Btw, even browsers do this differently here, an easy way to try on your own is to use http_build_query encoded URLs and paste them into the different browser's address bars and then compare how the URLs are changed.