# How to receive array URL

Tags: php, url

**I am sending the URL in below code**

```
$checkboxes = http_build_query($checkbox);
    echo "<script> document.location.href='index.php?act=magento&checkboxes=".$checkboxes."';</script>";
```

**I am getting URL below**

```
http://localhost/importcsvproduct/index.php?act=magento&checkboxes=0=15&1=16&2=17&3=18&4=19&5=20&6=21&7=22&8=23&9=24
```

**My question is how to receive this above checkboxes array?**

**My output of array $checkbox is below**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 17
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 19
    [5] => 20
    [6] => 21
    [7] => 22
    [8] => 23
    [9] => 24
)
```

Comment: This is simple php with `$_GET` and then access it as an' array!

Comment: This wont work.  Your query-string is being generated incorrectly.  Look at `&checkboxes=0=15`..  This will not work, and prevent you getting these details from `$_GET`

Comment: can you tell me how can i make correct url?

Comment: can you add what is the normal output of `$checkbox`.

Comment: Hey you can see output of $checkbox.

Comment: Sorry Maytham, I was trying to run this code. tell me friend?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
$checkbox = array(4,5,6,7,8); // Does your array look like this?
$checkboxes = http_build_query(array('checkboxes' => $checkbox));
echo "<script> document.location.href='index.php?act=magento&checkboxes=".$checkboxes."';</script>";
```

You should be able to access the checkbox value by using `$_GET['checkboxes']`:

```
$_GET['checkboxes'][0]
$_GET['checkboxes'][1]
...
```

Comment: Hey see my $checkbox output.

Comment: That looks great - so the code in my answer should work. Have you already tested it?

Comment: Maybe you also have to `urldecode` `$checkboxes` before outputting it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046623/http-build-query-functions-excessive-urlencoding