# W3 Validator is give me an error for > at the end of my <a> tag in html 5

Tags: html, validation

I'm running some code for a webpage through the W3 HTML5 validator and am getting the following error:

```
3 Line 29 Column 346: Bad value Iinterior-lighting?f[O]field_design_style%3A169
for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query:
not a URL code point.
..tapi-inactive id=facetapi-link--151>Unspecified (80)<span c].ass=”element-in...
```

The > tag closing the  is the one that is causing the error. Here is the full line of code that is causing the error.

```
<div class="item-list"><ul class="facetapi-facetapi-checkbox-links facetapi-facet-field-design-style" id="facetapi-facet-search-apisearch-api-solr-index-block-field-design-style"><li class="leaf first"><a href="/interior-lighting?f[0]=field_design_style%3A169" rel="nofollow" class="facetapi-checkbox facetapi-inactive" id="facetapi-link--139">Unspecified (80)<span class="element-invisible"> Apply Unspecified filter </span></a></li>
```

Once again the thing that is causing the error is the > in the opening  tag.

This looks right to me and I think it might just be an error with the validator. There are 175 errors just like it on this page.

Thanks

Comment: the w3c validator is EXTREMELY pedantic about url encoding. your `[0]` should be `%5B0%5D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt),

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6
>   [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal
>   within square brackets ("[" and "]"). This is the only place where
>   square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.

So you should encode square brackets in the url.

(Shamelessly stealed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016737/2195721))