# Use CakePHP Http Client with Magento2 rest API search criteria

Tags: rest, magento, cakephp, oauth, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to send a GET request to a local Magento2 rest API to get all the orders after a certain time.  I'm following http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html#simple-search-using-a-timestamp. I'm using CakePHP 3.4's Http Client (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html) and have successfully integrated with Magento using Oauth1 and have no problems with simpler GET requests like `http://www.magento.dev.com/rest/V1/stockItems/:productSku`. It is a problem with passing the search criteria. The response is always a `401 Invalid Signature`.

Using Postman, I can get a valid response to `http://www.magento.dev.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-07-01 00:00:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt`

This is what I have so far/how I'm sending the request:

**In Model/Table/OrdersTable.php:**

```
public function importNewOrders(\App\Model\Entity\OauthIntegration $integrationDetails)
    {
       $this->OauthIntegrations = TableRegistry::get('OauthIntegrations');
       $this->Orders = TableRegistry::get('Orders');
       $timeCutOff = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';
       $search = [
           'searchCriteria' => [
                'filterGroups' => [
                    0 => [
                        'filters' => [
                            0 => [
                                'field' => 'created_at',
                                'value' => $timeCutOff,
                                'condition_type' => 'gt'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
           ]
        ];
//           'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]' => 'created_at',
//           'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]' => $timeCutOff, 
//           'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]' => 'gt'

       $action = '/V1/orders';

       $type = "GET";
       $response = $this->OauthIntegrations->sendRequest(
               $integrationDetails, 
               $action, 
               $type,
               '',
               $search);

       Log::write('debug', $response->body());
       return $response;
    }
```

**and in Model\Table\OauthIntegrationsTable.php:**

```
public function sendRequest(\App\Model\Entity\OauthIntegration $integrationDetails, 
            string $action, string $method = "GET", string $data = '', array $search = null)
    {

        $http = new Client([
            'auth' => [
                'type' => 'oauth',
                'consumerKey' => $integrationDetails->oauth_consumer_key,
                'consumerSecret' => $integrationDetails->oauth_consumer_secret,
                'token' => $integrationDetails->oauth_token,
                'tokenSecret' => $integrationDetails->oauth_token_secret
              ]
          ]);
        $url = $integrationDetails->store_base_url . 'rest' . $action;
        if ($method == 'GET'){
            if (!isset($search)){
                $search = [];
            }
            $response = $http->get($url, $search, []);

        } else if ($method == 'POST'){

            $response = $http->post($url, $data, [
              'type' => 'json',

            ]);

        } else if($method == 'PUT'){
            $response = $http->put($url, $data, [
              'type' => 'json',
            ]);
        }
        Log::write('debug', 'url: ' . $url . ' and status code: ' . $response->getStatusCode());
        return $response;
    }
```

and this is the error (I'm hoping) is the cause of the Invalid Signature response:

```
2017-03-28 10:07:01 Notice: Notice (8): Array to string conversion in [/var/www/cakephp/html/beacon/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Client/Auth/Oauth.php, line 315]
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 153
Cake\Http\Client\Auth\Oauth::_normalizedParams() - CORE/src/Http/Client/Auth/Oauth.php, line 315
Cake\Http\Client\Auth\Oauth::baseString() - CORE/src/Http/Client/Auth/Oauth.php, line 246
Cake\Http\Client\Auth\Oauth::_hmacSha1() - CORE/src/Http/Client/Auth/Oauth.php, line 143
Cake\Http\Client\Auth\Oauth::authentication() - CORE/src/Http/Client/Auth/Oauth.php, line 61
Cake\Http\Client::_addAuthentication() - CORE/src/Http/Client.php, line 501
Cake\Http\Client::_createRequest() - CORE/src/Http/Client.php, line 448
Cake\Http\Client::_doRequest() - CORE/src/Http/Client.php, line 341
Cake\Http\Client::get() - CORE/src/Http/Client.php, line 211
App\Model\Table\OauthIntegrationsTable::sendRequest() - APP/Model/Table/OauthIntegrationsTable.php, line 134
App\Model\Table\OrdersTable::importNewOrders() - APP/Model/Table/OrdersTable.php, line 672
App\Shell\MagentoShell::main() - APP/Shell/MagentoShell.php, line 36
Cake\Console\Shell::runCommand() - CORE/src/Console/Shell.php, line 472
Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::_dispatch() - CORE/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 227
Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 182
Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::run() - CORE/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 128
[main] - ROOT/bin/cake.php, line 33
```

Code from Http\Client\Oauth.php where error occurs:

```
        $pairs = [];
        foreach ($args as $k => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                sort($val, SORT_STRING);
                Log::write('debug', 'about to go through foreach($val as $nestedVal)');
                foreach ($val as $nestedVal) {
                    Log::write('debug', $nestedVal);
                    $pairs[] = "$k=$nestedVal"; // <<< HERE
                }
            } else {
                $pairs[] = "$k=$val";
            }
        }
```

debugging from above results in:

```
2017-03-28 10:07:01 Debug: about to go through foreach($val as $nestedVal)
2017-03-28 10:07:01 Debug: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filters] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [field] => created_at
                            [value] => 2015-01-01 00:00:00
                            [condition_type] => gt
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

In summary, is it possible to pass a multi-dimensional array to the 2nd parameter in a get request using Cake's Http Client?

```
// Is it possible to replace ['q' => 'widget'] with a multi-dimensional array??
$response = $http->get('http://example.com/search', ['q' => 'widget']);
```

If not, what would be the best way to use Cake's Http Client to send GET request to: `http://www.magento.dev.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-07-01 00:00:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt` ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible bug

This may be considered as a possible bug. I don't think [**the OAuth specs**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4) take this PHP style bracket stuff in URLs into account, and therefore sorting/encoding the parameters is limited to flat `key=value` sets, ie a key would be

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]
```

and the value would be

```
created_at
```

The CakePHP OAuth adapter however parses the requests query string into a possibly deeply nested array structure, which will then fail, as it doesn't handle that case.

I'd suggest that you [**report this as a possible bug**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues). Further problems may occour as encoding seems to be ment to be applied before sorting, where in the CakePHP implementation, *additonal* parameter encoding is applied after sorting (that may actually be fine though, I'm not sure).

### Try a custom OAuth adapter as a workaround

Until this is being fixed/enhanced, you could use a custom OAuth adapter that handles things "properly" (whatever that means in this context). Here's a quick and dirty example (works for me with the Magento API).

Create **src/Http/Client/Auth/AppOAuth.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Client\Auth;

use Cake\Http\Client\Auth\Oauth;

class AppOAuth extends Oauth
{
    protected function _normalizedParams($request, $oauthValues)
    {
        $query = parse_url($request->url(), PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($query, $queryArgs);

        $post = [];
        $body = $request->body();
        if (is_string($body) &&
            $request->getHeaderLine('content-type') === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ) {
            parse_str($body, $post);
        }
        if (is_array($body)) {
            $post = $body;
        }

        $args = array_merge($queryArgs, $oauthValues, $post);
        $query = http_build_query($args);

        $args = [];
        foreach (explode('&', $query) as $value) {
            $pair = explode('=', $value, 2);
            $args[] =
                rawurlencode(rawurldecode($pair[0])) .
                '=' .
                rawurlencode(rawurldecode($pair[1]));
        }
        usort($args, 'strcmp');

        return implode('&', $args);
    }
}
```

Compare to **[\Cake\Http\Client\Auth\Oauth::_normalizedParams()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.4.3/src/Http/Client/Auth/Oauth.php#L279)**

Use it by specifying the classname in the `type` option for your client instance:

```
'type' => 'AppOAuth',
```

### ps

shouldn't it be `filter_groups` instead of `filterGroups` in your `$search` array?

Comment: Bug submitted: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10458.  Creating custom Oauth adapter like above solves the array to string notice but still has 401 invalid signature. The url is being passed with the square brackets being encoded as %5D and %5B. I tried using urldecode on the keys that include brackets from within AppOAuth.php but they are being encoded again before request is sent as debugging $url in cakephp/src//Http/Client.php protected function _doRequest($method, $url, $data, $options) has the brackets encoded.  Could that encoding cause the 401? I appreciate the help!

Comment: @BSounder AFAICT that should be fine, it's just percent encoded, totally valid for a URL. I can have another look at your specific conditions, I tried it with different ones.

Comment: That's what I thought too, especially since everything I've seen points to square brackets in url's as going against URI standards (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/are-square-brackets-permitted-in-urls / http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) so therefore they should be encoded

Comment: @BSounder Looks like the space in the date value is the problem in this case, it should end up as `%252B` when generating the signature, however it makes it there as `%2B` only, which seems to stem from the fact the when reading the URL from the request object in `_normalizedParams()`, it is present as `+`, and not already as `%2B`. Not sure who's correct here, I haven't delved too deeply into the OAuth RFC, but I could imagine that Magento is correct in requiring this.

Comment: @BSounder Updated the code example... works now, but things really get out of hand here, I have no idea if it works by chance, or if it really decodes/encodes things in the right place in the right way - I hate reading RFCs, and it's already 2 in the morning :)

Comment: @BSounder I couldn't stop thinking about it, so I came up with something new... I think this follows the RFC now, but I'm not 100% sure, after all it's already 4 in the morning now :) so, good night everyone, I'm out.

Comment: Haha @ndm you're the greatest!! Copied in your updated code and it worked immediately. Can't thank you enough! Get some sleep ;)