# How do I allow square brackets in my url in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have a url:

```
"http://example.com/some-var-[2009]-to-[2014]"
```

When I hit the same I get:

[image]

How do I fix the same ?
I want to allow square brackets [2009] & [2014] in my url.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/are-square-brackets-permitted-in-urls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=square+brackets+[url]

Comment: Cool. so they are not allowed at all. (Y)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are square brackets permitted in URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/are-square-brackets-permitted-in-urls)

Comment: Did you try to change $config['permitted_uri_chars']  in the config.php?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your config file in where permitted declared..

```
]a-z 0-9~%.:[_\-,;&()@!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your square bracket or other special characters after / those you want in URL like /[ or /] /@
Set in codeigniter_project/application/config/config.php configure this variable:

> $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_/-@/=/[/]';