# Mailchimp removing []?

Tags: mailchimp

I try to send some code samples via Mailchimp, and I've noticed that the `[]` characters are cut out. If something is inside the brackets, it goes out fine (a space is enough, so `[ ]` is fine).

This is the mail I design:

[image: Mailchimp designer]

What I see in Gmail:

[image: Gmail]

As you can see, the `[]`s are cut out.

When I view the mail in a browser (via the "View this email in your browser" link), the brackets are there.

Also if I click "Show original", the brackets are missing:

```
const result =3D ;
<pre><code>const result =3D ;</code></pre>
<code>const result =3D ;</code>
const result =3D [ ];
<pre><code>const result =3D [ ];</code></pre>
<code>const result =3D [ ];</code>
```

Because of this, I think Mailchimp is the one removing the brackets and not Gmail. I googled around, but was unable to find out why this is happening. I can reproduce it every time.

Comment: Looks like a bug in their parser. Did you contact their support?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this pops up for anyone (as it was the only post I could find online and it's from years ago)...  I was using Eventable and their Feed-specific share links for MailChimp included a `[]` in the URL and MailChimp kept removing it.

[I found the answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/are-square-brackets-permitted-in-urls)

Seems square brackets aren't standard for URLs and I tried replacing them with both what the link suggested as `%5B%5D` as well as `&#91;&#93;` which seems to be the code you'd use like when you do `&amp;` for & in HTML.

The `%5B%5D` ended up carrying through to the links and either visual converts to `[]` depending on mail application or stays `%5B%5D` if you do 'Copy Link' and paste it into the browser... but I guess the browser knows to convert it back to `[]`.

Hopefully this is helpful to someone!