# http url parameter Invalid Character Error

Tags: dart, flutter, feathersjs

I have developed a REST API using feathers.js (https://feathersjs.com/).
When trying to do a HTTP 'read' request in Flutter using package:http/http.dart I have encountered an error.  The http.dart library is unable to correctly parse the query params I pass to the URI.

The error I receive through the Android Studio debug console is ;

FormatException: Invalid character (at character 84) E/flutter
(11338): ...lk.com/weatherobs?last=true&location[$in]=Bellambi&location[$in]=Nowra ....

The error is indicating the square brackets and possibly the $ sign ('[$in]' ) are the issue.

```
_getDemoRequest() {
  String url = r"http://demoapi.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/weatherobs?last=true&location[$in]=Bellambi&location[$in]=Nowra&location[$in]=Sydney Airport&location[$in]=Thredbo Top Station&location[$in]=Hobart&location[$in]=Coolangatta";
  http.read(url).then(print);    
}
```

In the URL I have tried prefixing the String with and without 'r' for a raw string to no avail.

I have also tried using httpClient with params with no success and the exact same error on the square brackets eg '[$in]'

```
  String httpbaseUri = "http://xxxx.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com";
  String qParams = r"?last=true&location[$in]=Bellambi&location[$in]=Nowra";
  String path = "/weatherobs";
  var _uri = new Uri.http(baseUri, path, qParams);
  await httpClient.read(_uri, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
```

As a person with approximately 3 weeks of Flutter/Dart experience I believe its an elementary problem, but one in which several hours of research has uncovered no solution.

The ways the URI query parameters are structured (with the square brackets ie [$in]) are dictated by the feathers.js framework.

Any help would be appreciated.

It has been brought to my attention in another thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/are-square-brackets-permitted-in-urls](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) :

That the URL Specification  [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) generally does not permit square brackets in an URL.

My question was triggered as the get request works as intended in Postman, Chrome Browser and also javascript applications using [axios.js](https://github.com/axios/axios), but not in an application developed in Flutter/Dart using standard http.read methods.

Comment: Seems they are not allowed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/are-square-brackets-permitted-in-urls, perhaps it works if you encode the query https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Uri/encodeQueryComponent.html

Comment: Like https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c8f7914404fe02c407007d16e2463126

Comment: Superb answer Gunter. Replacing the square brackets with %5B and %5D as indicated worked. Thanks for the dartpad example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like `[]` are supported in the URL (except for the host IP for IPv6). See [Are square brackets permitted in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/are-square-brackets-permitted-in-urls).

Please check if the API accepts them when they are encoded like:

```
void main() {
    var url = r'http://demoapi.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/weatherobs';
    var locationKey = Uri.encodeQueryComponent(r'location[$in]');
    var qParams = 'last=true&$locationKey=Bellambi&$locationKey=Nowra&$locationKey=Sydney Airport&$locationKey=Thredbo Top Station&$locationKey=Hobart&$locationKey=Coolangatta'; 

    try {
      print(Uri.parse(url).replace(query: qParams));
    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }
}
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c8f7914404fe02c407007d16e2463126)

See also api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Uri/…

Answer (score 0):

You can use this flutter package which allow you to communicate with your feathers js server from flutter app as said in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65538226/12461921

Comment: Package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_feathersjs

Comment: You should put this as a comment