# Passing [] in HttpRequestMessage query parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, uri

I'm trying to pass a query parameter to a REST API. The parameter has [] characters in it, and I just cannot get it to work.

This is my code:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.eu.itglue.com/organizations");
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
```

This works, but this doesn't:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.eu.itglue.com/organizations?page[size]=1000");
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe square brackets have limitations in their URL usage, and you need to encode them to %5B and %5D, respectively.  Like this:

```
request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.eu.itglue.com/organizations?page%5Bsize%5D=1000");
```

More Info: [Are square brackets permitted in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/are-square-brackets-permitted-in-urls)

Comment: I tried that too, but it's still failing.